# Keep Views within screen bounds when using UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

Id like to keep some views with in the bounds of the screen but because of the uiscrollview when I add constraints it expands horizontally and my views become really big. The views should be contained with in the screen and the only scrolling that should be done is to access the views at the bottom. How would I do this? I do not want any horizontal scrolling, just vertical scrolling. Im using Swift 2.0 and Xcode 7

Comment: It is difficult to know what is being asked here.

Comment: When you add views to your `UIScrollView`, how does it expand horizontally?

Comment: Sorry about not being clear but basically what is happening is that my view s are constrianed to the UIScrollviews bounds. The uiscrollview keeps on expanding to accomadate the lengths of the views. Before I started using UIscrollviews I just constrained my views to screens bounds.